# Laravel - Hash check returns false even when its correct

Tags: laravel, hash, bcrypt

I was using md5 to login from a form and I am trying to switch to bcrypt, but the `Hashk::check` method always returns false, even if the password is correct, any idea why it is not working?

```
         $email = Input::get('email');
         $password =  Input::get('password');
         $user = User::where("email","=",$email)->first();

            if(Hash::check($password,$user->password)) {

                    $userID = $user->id_user;
                    $username = $user->first_name." ".$user->last_name;
                    $admin = "yes";
                    Session::put('userID',$userID);
                    Session::put('userName',$username);
                    Session::put('admin',$admin);
                    return redirect('/cw-admin/');
            } else {
                    return Redirect::to('/cw-admin/login')
                        ->withErrors(['no' => 'Incorrect password']);
            }
            }
```

EDIT added the User model, I only changed the fillables, primaryKey and ID, the methods are left empty.

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_user';

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name','last_name','password','email'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    }
```

dd output:

```
User {#592 ▼
  #table: "user"
  #primaryKey: "id_user"
  #fillable: array:4 [▼
    0 => "first_name"
    1 => "last_name"
    2 => "password"
    3 => "email"
  ]
  #hidden: array:2 [▼
    0 => "password"
    1 => "remember_token"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: By default in User model, password was hidden, so did you change that ? 

And can you show your `User` Model please, and can you `dd($user)`

Comment: Added them to original post

Comment: In my mind, i think it's should resolve, but i cant try :/ `$user->makeVisible('password')->toArray();`

Comment: APP key is the same since Laravel installation

Comment: for tests, if I do this:  `if(Hash::check('1234','the generated hash from DB'))` I still get  false, the hash to database is generated like `Hash::make($password)`;

Comment: Hash::check($user->password,$password), Hask::check will hash the second parameter in your sequence you've double hashed hence return false @ChrisFodor

Comment: I found the issue, the issue was that in my DB password was limited to VARCHAR(45) and the generated hash was longer than that. Silly me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check your User table definition. If Hashed field is returning false even if you are posting something to it, it is not retrieving the same value as the one you have posted.

In my case, I would use max length on column(s) that store hashed values.

`Alter Table Users Modify password VCHAR(255);`